# Select repeated values using an array containing repeated elements

Tags: postgresql

How can I select rows using an array of input values, where any repeated input values get a corresponding repeated output?

**Example:**

myTable is:

```
 key | name  
-----+-------
   1 | Alice
   2 | Bob
   3 | Chuck
```

and

`SELECT name FROM myTable WHERE key IN (1,1,2,3,3);`

gives:

```
 name  
-------
 Alice
 Bob
 Chuck
(3 rows)
```

This ignores the repetitions in the input array. I want to get this output:

```
 Alice
 Alice
 Bob
 Chuck
 Chuck
(5 rows)
```

**More explanation:**

We can select rows using an array of input values and the IN operator.

But repeated values in the array are ignored: it is effectively using the distinct input values as a set.

I want to get N outputs from N input values, even if some inputs are repeated.

Note: I am using PostgreSQL 12.9 and psycopg2 from python3, though that presumably makes no difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can unnest an array and join it with your table :

```
select * 
from myTable m
join unnest(array[1,1,2,3,3]) keys (k)
on m.key = keys.k
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=1009e969f61fefe6c77121a85cdbdeac)*

Comment: Thanks, that's excellent. And in psycopg2 it becomes:
```cursor.execute("SELECT name from myTable m join unnest(%s) keys on m.key = keys",([1,1,2,3,3],))```

Comment: No: passing in a Python list makes the "ARRAY" keyword appear magically! See "lists adaptation" here https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html

Answer (score 1):

You can `select` a `union` of your keys in a CTE, then `join` it to your table:

```
with keys as
(select 1 as key
union all select 1
union all select 2
union all select 3
union all select 3)
select name
from keys natural join myTable;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=0e92dddcea1c372dad5121a12b2af0d1)

Comment: Thank you, this works. However, it is best if the array is kept together, as in the other answer.